# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed, Python sockets, ssl, gmail smtp connect

Tags: python, sockets, email, ssl

I want to connect to gmail SMTP server using secure sockets. I have downloaded the `mail.google.com.crt` cert file by using my browser - Firefox (I simply opened a `gmail.com` page and then exported the certificate using my browser export cert button).

However, its seems that there is a problem, and I do not know why. when I changed `mail.google.com.crt` to `GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem` (I found it somewhere online) it worked (didnt show the erros). Am I not understand something here?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    PORT = 465

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.load_verify_locations('mail.google.com.crt')

    # check SNI extension
    if ssl.HAS_SNI:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST)
    else:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock)

    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print cert

    if not cert or ('commonName', 'smtp.google.com') not in cert['subject'][4]: raise Exception("erroe" )

    secure_sock.recv(1024)

    secure_sock.close()
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> context.load_verify_locations('mail.google.com.crt')
> ```

Verify locations are expected to contain trusted CA certificates. The server certificate you've specified is no CA certificate. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations):

> Load a set of “certification authority” (CA) certificates used to validate other peers’ certificates  ...

Comment: I see, thank you. So it seems that I should always export the first (from up to bottom) certificate, because only this one is trusted?

Comment: Does it also mean that if I would like to build my own CA, this would not work? And how about self-signed certificates?

Comment: @yak: if you would built your own CA you can simply add your own root CA. And with self-signed it will work as long as these are a CA too (which the usually are but not always). And *"because only this one is trusted?"* : nothing is trusted unless you declare it as trusted.